# Want to manage mongoldb user on CodeIgniter using Parse Rest API

Tags: php, mongodb, rest, codeigniter, parse-platform

Database: Mongodb
Backend Framework: CodeIgniter

Want to manage default User table from backend. I am using ParseRestAPI but as you all know Mongodb does not allow to update user without session. So is there any way i can manage users created by App and delete/create new users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that with the Parse Rest API

For exmaple to delete a user:
Use the DELETE http verb and call something like that:

**Note**: You need to pass the Session Token or Master Key

```
 curl -X DELETE \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: YOURAPPID" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: YOURAPIKEY" \
  -H "X-Parse-Session-Token: SESSIONTOKEN" \
  -H "X-Parse-Master-Key: YOURMASTERKEY" \
  https://api.example.com/1/users/<objectId>
```

In php you can write:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://api.example.com/1/users/<objectId>');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");                                                                     

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'X-Parse-Application-Id: YOURAPPID',
    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key: YOURAPIKEY', 
    'X-Parse-Master-Key: YOURMASTERKEY'                                                                 
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

To create a user call the API like that (I use curl for example)

```
        curl -X POST \
        -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: YOUAPPID" \
        -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: YOURAPIKEY" \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -d '{ "objectId": "", "updatedAt": "", "createdAt": "", "name": "John Doe", "pass": "toto42" }' \
        https://api.example.com/1/classes/User/
```

Comment: Using same curl and then send the following JSON to update just like you sent, but got following error
[code] => 400
[response] => {"code":206,"error":"Cannot modify user 06mqGTKBTr."}

Comment: @MMuzammilQ I've forgotten an important thing, I've update my answer

Comment: I asked in my question that i want to do it from CodeIgniter backend and want to update in bulk. I am using same curl in APP and its working fine.

Comment: @MMuzammilQ  
Did you pass the master key or session token ?

Comment: I can not pass session token because i am updating the user in bulk and i want to do CRUD from backend. Its not like user logged in and then update.

Comment: @MMuzammilQ So just pass the master key

Comment: @MMuzammilQ Perfect 

Comment: I asked another question please check if you can help me. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45314137/mongodb-trying-to-call-user-logged-rest-api-call-but-facing-issue

Comment: @MMuzammilQ Thank you, I'll take a look 