# MongoDB Trying to call User logged Rest API Call but facing issue

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter, parse-platform

I am trying to call User Logged API Call for MongoDb but faced following issue.

BackEnd: CodeIgniter
Parse Rest API Call to connect MongoDB.
_UserArray
(
    [code] => 102
    [error] => Improper encode of parameter
)

> Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ParseException' with message 'Improper encode of parameter' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/icymi/application/libraries/Parse/ParseClient.php:264 
>   Stack trace:
>   0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/icymi/application/libraries/Parse/ParseUser.php(136): ParseClient::_request('GET', '/1/login', '', Array) 
>   1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/icymi/application/controllers/manage.php(519): ParseUser::logIn('admin', 'Test@123')
>   2 [internal function]: manage->console_menu()
>   3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/icymi/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(359): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
>   4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/icymi/index.php(203): require_once('/Applications/X...')
>   5 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/icymi/application/libraries/Parse/ParseClient.php on line 264

Comment: Can you show me your code please

Comment: $pushUrl = 'http://eb-icymyi-parse-server.jegr4ium5p.us-east-
      $headers = array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",  
    "X-Parse-Application-Id: " . $appId,
    "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: " . $restKey
);          

$username = urlencode('username=test@abv.bg');
$password = urlencode('password=test');
$url = $pushUrl."/1/login/?$username&$password";

Comment: $rest = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_URL,$url);  
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_HTTPGET,1);
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"GET");  
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);  
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($rest);  
echo $response;